# Collapsible profile section on own profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, gravatar

The profile page serves several purposes but these can be different depending on whether we are viewing our own profile page or that of another user. I think a lot of us use our own profile page to keep track of discussions we're having. We already know how we've described ourselves so the profile and gravatar section at the top is just distracting from the information we've come to the page for.

Pretty please with waffles on top can we find a way to hide (or make less prominent) the top section of the profile page and gravatar image when we are looking at our own profile? I'm quite happy to see all that gubbins when I'm on another user's profile page. In that case it adds something to the UX but I'm tired of seeing my own profile all the time.

Perhaps others have ideas about the best way of implementing this or some variation of the idea that is more appealing.

Comment: Perhaps splitting out an "Activity" section would help?